# Can't get stream with PHP Guzzle using proxy

Tags: guzzle

I'm using Guzzle 6.3 with Laravel. I have this code:

```
$url = 'http://dest_ip:dest_port';

$client = new Client();

$res = $client->request('GET', $url, [
    //    'proxy' => 'http://proxy_ip:80',
        'stream' => true,
    ]);

$body = $res->getBody();

header("Content-Type:{$res->getHeader('Content-Type')[0]}");

while (! $body->eof())
    echo $body->read(256);
```

It works fine but as you can see I commented line with proxy settings. When I'm trying to use it returns an error:

> Error creating resource: [message] `fopen(http://dest_ip:dest_port)`: failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "http" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

If I use tcp for proxy:

```
'proxy' => 'tcp://proxy_ip:80'
```

it gives me no errors but instead leads to directory `'/var/www/html'` on the proxy server. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally found the solution. I had to dig deeper and handle my stream with fsockopen().

```
$fp = fsockopen($proxy_ip, $proxy_port, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "GET http://$url:$port\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nHTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);

    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 256);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```